# using localisation with strftime on ESP32 FreeRTOS

Tags: c++, time, localization, esp32, freertos

I am trying to format a date in a given locale on FreeRTOS on an ESP32. Consider the following code:

```
#define LC_TIME "de_DE"
void getLocalizedDateTest(char* s,size_t max){
    struct timeval t;
  tm localTime;
  gettimeofday(&t,NULL);
  time_t tt = t.tv_sec;
  localtime_r(&tt, &localTime);
  setenv("LC_TIME",LC_TIME,1);
  strftime(s,max,"%A, %B",&localTime); 
}
```

According to my research, LC_TIME controls the way strftime works, so this should yield months and weekdays in German. However, the strings stubbornly remain the standard english ones.

What am I missing? Is what I want to do even possible, or am I going about this in entirely the wrong way?

Comment: Consider this - if Espressif included localization support for every language in the world, an application printing out "Hello world" would probably not fit into the Flash. It makes sense that they do the absolute minimum. newlib [support for locales](https://sourceware.org/newlib/libc.html#Locale) is bare bones anyway. So I don't think you're going to get it to speak German unless you do it yourself.

Comment: Your research probably shows it is for the environment running a linux or unix operating system and all the locale modules installed in the hard disk, not for an MCU like ESP32.

Comment: hcheung this is true - it is hard to come by information specific for FreeRTOS on ESP32, so I've read pretty much anything I could get my hands on pertaining to strftime, including an implementation by apple from 1999, just to get a feel of how it is done. The question remaining is: Is there any mechanism in place in the ESP32 toolchain to implement and plumb in such localisation? I'd be perfectly happy to invest the time if there is such a thing.

Comment: Localization is a feature of the C library. Espressif is using newlib, which may or may not have support for anything other than the fallback "C" locale (I've never looked into it, check out the link I posted earlier). I very much doubt that Espressif has anything prepared to help you. It would probably be much easier to write your code to format dates and other such from scratch.

Comment: Tarmo it appears you are right. Newlib itself seems to have the functionality to handle locales, but the ESP32 toolchain only contains a very small subset of newlib apparently. The espressif header files seem not to reference anything about locales. So strftime goes into the trash, Hi ho, hi ho, to write formatters we go... Fun! Thanks anyway for your contribution.